# Additional scrollbars showing when reviewing questions in the Review queue

Tags: bug

I've just noticed that additional vertical (and horizontal) scrollbars are appearing when reviewing questions in the "First Posts" review queue. I've not noticed it in other review queues (but I've not seen/tested them all).

The vertical scrollbar appears immediately on viewing the page, but the horizontal scrollbar may only appear after some seconds delay, as if this is dependent on some JavaScript running?!

This seems to be reasonably "unique" to Webmasters SE as far as I can tell (or maybe not?). At least I don't see it on StackOverflow, ServerFault, SuperUser, WordPress and Android Enthusiasts. Although I do see the scrollbars on "English Language & Usage" and WebApps also.

**UPDATE:**

- The scrollbars only seem to show when reviewing "questions". (When reviewing an "answer" then there is naturally a question below it that *stretches* the container and avoids the scrollbars from showing.)
- I think these scrollbars may have started with the introduction of the "New contributor" *badges* immediately below the users signature panel. If you `display:none` these *badges* then the scrollbars are also removed.

  [image: Signature with "New contributor" badge]
- The "First Posts" review queue naturally gets all the "new contributors" so that may also explain why I'm only seeing the scrollbars in the "First Posts" review queue.

---

Chrome (Version 68.0.3440.106) on Windows Desktop. Browser window is maximised on a 1920 x 1200 pixel display, viewing at 100% (ie. no zoom).

[image: First Posts review queue showing scrollbars]

The above screenshot is *cropped* from a larger 1920 x 1200 pixel image:

[image: First Posts review queue - Screenshot Overview]

Comment: I've noticed this as well around the time of the most recent redesign.

Comment: @dan I'm wondering if it's related to the "New contributor" badges below the users' signature? I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a design issue that is not localised to Pro Webmasters. It happens on most Stacks, not all just most (SO works fine etc).

The main container `#content` uses `width: 1060px` therefore any resolutions or window sizes below this resolution will result in a visible `overflow`.

Generally, this is not a problem for most users viewing the website using a browser that is in maximized in size. If people are experiencing the issue on anything higher than 1060px then they are most likely have the zoom increased in their browser. A browser window of 1680x1050 px with 150% zoom will cause an overflow, as would `1280x1080` at 25% zoom.

The quick fix is to ensure your browser window is above 1060px and without zoom enabled.

Hopefully, at some point, the designers will abandon 'float: left;` with static widths in favour of flex with responsive containers.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is referring to the same thing? The scrollbars that I see (on the fixed width area containing the post for review) do not seem to be dependent on window size. The screenshot in my question is actually cropped from a larger screenshot on a maximised browser window on a 1920 x 1200 screen and viewed at 100% (no zoom) - I've also added this to my question. "It happens on most Stacks" - which other stacks do you see this on?

Comment: It happens on loads of stacks... the base template (width:) on #content is replicated on most stacks, only one that I know doesn't is Stack Overflow. Reduce your resolution or window size to 1680px and increase zoom to 50%. Furthermore, it seems that you noticed this during a 'review' of flags, does this occur in other situations? also, what resolution/browser are you using?

Comment: "increase zoom to 50%" - don't you mean 150%? Either way, changing window size and increasing/decreasing zoom makes little difference to this particular problem. This only seems to occur when "reviewing First Posts" (or viewing the history of "First Posts"). This also seems to only apply when reviewing "questions", rather than "answers" ("answers" naturally stretch the inner content area). I also haven't seen it on the other review queues. So they do not always appear. As mentioned above, I'm viewing this maximised on a 1920x1200 screen (at 100% zoom) using Google Chrome v68.0.3440.106

Comment: Most likely something to do with the reviews page. It's most likely happening on all Stacks and yes I meant 150%.

Comment: I think this may have something to do with the introduction of the "New contributor" _badges_ below the users' signature. I've only noticed these scrollbars recently and if you hide the "New controbutor" _badge_ the scrollbars also dissappear. The "First Posts" review queue naturally gets all the "new contributors". (I've updated my question.)